# how to include css file in thyemeaf fragment

Tags: css, fragment, thymeleaf

I Have a template decorator as the base html page and many html pages with fragments , and i want to include css file in html fragment pages, when I place the css file at the top of the fragment html page, it doesn't load because only thymeleaf only take into consideration what is in fragement, I don't want to include all css files in the base html page (the template or decorator)

Comment: This is not something that is possible with Thymeleaf. Fragments are a way to split up chuncks of HTML so they can be re-used. There is no concept of combining HTML with CSS and then generating a final HTML with a final CSS file.

Comment: thank you very much, seems that thymeleaf is getting things complicated

Answer (score 0):

You could add all the fragment css in separate files and link to these files in the head section of your html decorator using `<link rel = "stylesheet">` tags.

For example:

```
<head>
    <link th:href="@{../css/footer_fragment.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

You can add multiple of these link tags, one for each fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head th:fragment="head">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Coding Events</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}">
</head>
```

Here's a fragment head that actually works for me. You need the `th:` in front of `href`.